# Creating network from csv file (Python, Pandas, Networkx)

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I have a csv file that I want to make a network out of.

The csv file I have looks something like this

| Company | Investors |
| --- | --- |
| (comp1) | (investorA) |
| (comp2) | (investorB) |
| (comp3) | (investorC) |
| (comp4) | (investorB, investorC) |

I am using pandas and networkx on python.

My network's nodes will be each companies and investors.

I think I can make it work if each row had only one investor (like comp1~3)
But, I am having trouble with rows with multiple investors.

I am very new to coding. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.DataFrame.explode`:

```
df_e = df.explode('Investors')
nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_e, 'Company', 'Investors')
```

If Investors is a string and not a tuple, you can use the following

```
df['Investors'] = df['Investors'].str.strip('\[|\]').str.split(',')
df_e = df.explode('Investors')
nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df_e, 'Company', 'Investors')
```